# Excel: import from web

Tags: excel, excel-web-query

For some reason, the web import fails with this website! What I am looking for is the table that is generated after choosing the needed filter.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=windows%2010

The required table appears in the "New Web Query" window, but when I click import if fails to import returning an Error Msg "This web query returned no data".

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand your issue. I can import the table data from that website fine. **What** are you trying to do, **why** do you need the data _that_ way, **how** are you trying, and **what**'s going wrong?

Comment: I am trying to import the table that is generated. I want excel to check that page every week to update the "Mainstream Support End Date and Extended Support End Date". The import fails for me..I am using Excel 2013. I need to table to be imported to excel as it appears in the website.

Comment: try to follow my steps exactly, below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These steps work for me:

- Create a new blank workbook (I'm using Excel 2016.)
- Go to `Data` tab → `From Web`
- In the `From Web` window paste: 1https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=windows%20101 and then click <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image: web data]

- Click `Table 0` and then <kbd>Load</kbd>

[image: web data load]

- A few seconds later the data is loaded.

[image: web data loaded]

---

### Update:

I noticed that after I repeated the same steps 3 or 4 times, the page no longer loads for me, which is likely due to the site detecting scraping and temporarily blocking me (and probably the same for you).

Anyway [here is a link to a workbook via Jump Share](http://jmp.sh/5MMmwSI) with the table attached & loaded for you.  Note that it won't work on the web version, you'll need to download with the blue Download button.

Let me know if it works for you.

---

### Update #2:

An alternative option is to use the pages' CSV Export rather than scraping the page:

- Go to `Data` tab → `From Text/CSV`
- In the `Import Data` dialog, paste this address:

> `https://support.microsoft.com/api/lifecycle/GetProductsLifecycle?query=%7B%22names%22:%5B%22windows%252010%22%5D,%22years%22:%220%22,%22gdsId%22:0,%22export%22:true%7D`

- Leave the defaults as-is assuming they are:

> File Origin: `65001: Unicode (UTF-8)`
>
> Delimiter: `Comma`

- Click <kbd>Load</kbd>.  A moment later, the data appears as a table on a worksheet.